# CAS Authenticate through another subdomain

Tags: cas, jasig, phpcas

At my place of employment, we do not control what applications are CAS authorized, but have existing CAS authorization for an application hosted at foobar.com/app-one.

When a user signs into this, they are correctly authenticated, and are served the application. 
Recently, we have added a new application, foobar.com/app-two. Unfortunately when signing in, the user is served a message "Application Not Authorized to use CAS". For reference, both of these have CAS server validation disabled.

However, if a user accesses foobar.com/app-one, authenticates themselves, then navigates to foobar.com/app-two, the page is served without issue.

How would I have an unauthenticated user access app-two, get directed to the authorized login component of app-one, and then be redirected to app-two?

EDIT: Could I pass a new redirect location in my request or something similar?

Comment: The problem is, why `Application Not Authorized to use CAS` problem exists for app2? Maybe foobar.com/app-two is not registered as a valid service?  https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Service-Management.html

Comment: @NgSekLong The app-two is not registered with the CAS server. I am hoping to find a way to authenticate users with the foobar.com/app-one service which IS valid. and then serve app-two once the user is authenticated

Comment: So you just want to redirect to app-two from app-one? Can you make a page in app-one, and do something like this: `http://cas.example.com?service=http://foobar.com/app-one/redirect?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffoobar.com%2Fapp-two`, will this work for you?